# AccessViolationException with sound buffer conversion

Tags: c#, type-conversion, access-violation, naudio, asio

I'm using **Naudio AsioOut** object to pass data from input buffer to my `delayProc()` function and then to output buffer.

The `delayProc()` needs `float[]` buffer type, and this is possible using `e.GetAsInterleavedSamples()`. The problem is I need to re-convert it to a multidimensional `IntPtr`, to do this I'm using `AsioSampleConvertor` class.

When I try to apply the effect it shows me an error: **AccessViolationException** on the code of `AsioSampleConvertor` class.

So I think the problem is due to the conversion from `float[]` to `IntPtr[]`..

I give you some code:

**OnAudioAvailable()**

```
floatIn = new float[e.SamplesPerBuffer * e.InputBuffers.Length];//*2

e.GetAsInterleavedSamples(floatIn);

floatOut = delayProc(floatIn, e.SamplesPerBuffer * e.InputBuffers.Length, 1.5f);
//conversione da float[] a IntPtr[L][R]
Outp = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float)*floatOut.Length);

Marshal.Copy(floatOut, 0, Outp, floatOut.Length);
NAudio.Wave.Asio.ASIOSampleConvertor.ConvertorFloatToInt2Channels(Outp, e.OutputBuffers, e.InputBuffers.Length, floatOut.Length);
```

**delayProc()**

```
private float[] delayProc(float[] sourceBuffer, int sampleCount, float delay)
{
    if (OldBuf == null)
    {
        OldBuf = new float[sampleCount];
    }
    float[] BufDly = new float[(int)(sampleCount * delay)];
    int delayLength = (int)(BufDly.Length - (BufDly.Length / delay));
    for (int j = sampleCount - delayLength; j < sampleCount; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < delayLength; i++)
            BufDly[i] = OldBuf[j];
    for (int j = 0; j < sampleCount; j++)
        for (int i = delayLength; i < BufDly.Length; i++)
            BufDly[i] = sourceBuffer[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
        OldBuf[i] = sourceBuffer[i];
    return BufDly;
}
```

**AsioSampleConvertor**

```
public static void ConvertorFloatToInt2Channels(IntPtr inputInterleavedBuffer, IntPtr[] asioOutputBuffers, int nbChannels, int nbSamples)
{
    unsafe
    {
        float* inputSamples = (float*)inputInterleavedBuffer;
        int* leftSamples = (int*)asioOutputBuffers[0];
        int* rightSamples = (int*)asioOutputBuffers[1];

        for (int i = 0; i < nbSamples; i++)
        {
            *leftSamples++ = clampToInt(inputSamples[0]);
            *rightSamples++ = clampToInt(inputSamples[1]);
            inputSamples += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**ClampToInt()**

```
private static int clampToInt(double sampleValue)
{
    sampleValue = (sampleValue < -1.0) ? -1.0 : (sampleValue > 1.0) ? 1.0 : sampleValue;
    return (int)(sampleValue * 2147483647.0);
}
```

If you need some other code, just ask me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `ConvertorFloatToInt2Channels` you are passing in the total number of samples across all channels, then trying to read that many *pairs* of samples.  So you are trying to read twice as many samples from your input buffer as are actually there.  Using unsafe code you are trying to address well past the end of the allocated block, which results in the access violation you are getting.

Change the `for` loop in your `ConvertorFloatToInt2Channels` method to read:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbSamples; i += 2)
```

This will stop your code from trying to read double the number of items actually present in the source memory block.

---

Incidentally, why are you messing around with allocating global memory and using unsafe code here?  Why not process them as managed arrays?  Processing the data itself isn't much slower, and you save on all the overheads of copying data to and from unmanaged memory.

Try this:

```
public static void FloatMonoToIntStereo(float[] samples, float[] leftChannel, float[] rightChannel)
{
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < samples.Length; i += 2, j++)
    {
        leftChannel[j] = (int)(samples[i] * Int32.MaxValue);
        rightChannel[j] = (int)(samples[i + 1] * Int32.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

On my machine that processes around 12 million samples per second, converting the samples to integer and splitting the channels.  About half that speed if I allocate the buffers for every set of results.  About half again when I write that to use unsafe code, `AllocHGlobal` etc.

Never assume that unsafe code is faster.